# Infinitive after komenci

Tags: infinitive

How would you say *He started to speak*?

Would that be *Li komencis paroli*?

In other languagues there is normally a particle next to the infinitive form: *he started to speak* (English); *comenzó a hablar* (Spanish); *er fing an, zu sprechen* (German).

How would it be with the verb *fini*?

Comment: I suppose it's Slavic influence. Both Russian начал говорить and Polish zaczął mówić are past tense verb + infinitive, and IIRC these languages shaped Esperanto just as much as English, German and French.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you just say *komencis paroli* with no extra particle. If you search for this in the [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/) there are many examples, such as this one from Zamenhof’s translation of Andersen’s fables:

> Nun unu el la burĝoj **komencis paroli** pri la terura pesto, kiu furiozis antaŭ kelke da jaroj

It’s the same for *fini*. Here is an example from *Gerda Malaperis*.

> Gerda sentas sin pli bone. Ŝi ĵus **finis manĝi**.

I think the only time where you would translate the *to* before an infinitive in English is when it could be replaced with “in order to”. In that case you can add *por* before the infinitive. For example “I jumped to avoid the car” could become:

> Mi saltis **por eviti** la aŭton.

Comment: In the case of *paroli*, wouldn't perhaps *li ĉesis paroli* be a slightly better fit?

Comment: @LaVo-o I think they’d have slightly different meanings. To my mind _finis paroli_ means the person said everything they wanted to say and stopped, whereas _ĉesis paroli_ might mean they realised they were talking too much and stopped before finishing.

Answer (score 5):

- Li ekparolis
- Li komencis paroli

Of course *ekparoli* is far better, but an infinitive is fine too.

Comment: Why would you say that *ekparoli* is far better? They mean different things. The best wording depends on what you are trying to say.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander Yes, though with the same meaning, `ek` stresses a point in time, whereas `komencis` could be a duration. "far better" is not really what I meant; `ekparoli` is more better display of language power, using Esperanto to its fullest. Possible for "start to read" = _eklegi_, "start to write" = _ekskribi_. Definite for "stand up" = _ekstari_, "sit down" = _eksidi_, "fall asleep" = _ekdormi_.

Comment: "Mia filino komencis paroli de tre frua agxo." -- "Mi ne scias kiu li estas. Li simple iris al la mikrofono kaj ekparolis."

Comment: @TomasoAlexander very good examples.

Answer (score 4):

If the purpose of the question is to find a parallel in a national language, consider that the infinitive in Esperanto often corresponds to the *-ing* form in English: *he started speaking*.

This rule of thumb often works with other verbs.

- He finished speaking - li finis paroli.
- He considered speaking - li pripensis paroli

The tricky part is to know when you do need a little word (like *por*) - but that's answered here:

[When should "por" be used before an infinitive (i-verbo)?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/951/when-should-por-be-used-before-an-infinitive-i-verbo)